# Gerar tabela ao clicar no botão

Tags: javascript

Em um HTMl simples, com titulo e um botão! Quero criar uma tabela sempre que clicar no botão!
A tabela deve ter escrito na celular

```
linha 0, coluna 0 | linha 0, coluna 1 | linha 0, coluna 3

linha 1, coluna 0 | linha 1, coluna 1 | linha 1, coluna 3
```

e assim segue!

mas eu travei na crianção disso!

```
  let tabela = document.getElementById("tabela")

  let linha0 = ["Linha 0 e Coluna 0", "Linha 0 e Coluna 1", "Linha 0 e Coluna 3"]

  let linha1 = ["Linha 1 e Coluna 0", "Linha 1 e Coluna 1", "Linha 1 e Coluna 3"]

  let linha2 = ["Linha 2 e Coluna 0", "Linha 2 e Coluna 1", "Linha 2 e Coluna 3"]

  let td0 = document.createElement("td")
  let td1 = document.createElement("td")
  let td2 = document.createElement("td")

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr")
    tr.innerHTML = linha0 [i]
    td0.appendChild(tr)
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr")
    tr.innerHTML = linha0 [i]
    td1.appendChild(tr)
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr")
    tr.innerHTML = linha0 [i]
    td2.appendChild(tr)
  }

  tabela.appendChild(td0)
  tabela.appendChild(td1)
  tabela.appendChild(td2)

}
```

Comment: Falta `document.createElement('tr')` pra gerar as linhas e dentro de cada TR gerado voce vai gerar os TDs, falta tambem o appendChild, na documentacao da MDN tem todos links com exemplos de uso: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement, o MDN ja ensina bem. **Nota:** Os comentários [foram movidos para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147929). Antes de postar um comentário no site leia [O que são os comentários?](/help/privileges/comment). Para dúvidas complementares de uso do site segue orientações em [meta-tag:faq].